# Index dummy variables in R

Tags: r

My data looks like this

```
> data
         Date Dummy
1  2020-01-01     1
2  2020-01-02     0
3  2020-01-03     0
4  2020-01-04     0
5  2020-01-05     1
6  2020-01-06     1
7  2020-01-07     1
8  2020-01-08     0
9  2020-01-09     1
10 2020-01-10     1
11 2020-01-11     0
```

I want to add a column which would index consecutive 1s in dummies so that my final data looks like this.

```
> data
         Date Dummy Dummy_Modified
1  2020-01-01     1              1
2  2020-01-02     0              0
3  2020-01-03     0              0
4  2020-01-04     0              0
5  2020-01-05     1              1
6  2020-01-06     1              2
7  2020-01-07     1              3
8  2020-01-08     0              0
9  2020-01-09     1              1
10 2020-01-10     1              2
11 2020-01-11     0              0
```

How can I achieve this in R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `data.table`, we can use the `rleid` function.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table', grouped by `rleid(Dummy`), we create a new column (`Dummy_Modified`) by assigning (`:=`) the output of 'Dummy' multiplied by the sequence of rows (`seq_len(.N)`) so that the 0 values in 'Dummy' will remain as 0 in the output.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, Dummy_Modified := Dummy * seq_len(.N), by = rleid(Dummy)]
data
#          Date Dummy Dummy_Modified
# 1: 2020-01-01     1              1
# 2: 2020-01-02     0              0
# 3: 2020-01-03     0              0
# 4: 2020-01-04     0              0
# 5: 2020-01-05     1              1
# 6: 2020-01-06     1              2
# 7: 2020-01-07     1              3
# 8: 2020-01-08     0              0
# 9: 2020-01-09     1              1
#10: 2020-01-10     1              2
#11: 2020-01-11     0              0
```

---

Using `dplyr`, we can make use of `lag` to check whether the adjancent elements in 'Dummy' are same or not, get the `cumsum` of the logical index for creating a grouping column ('gr'), then we use the same method as above to get the 'Dummy_Modified'.  The `row_number()` in `dplyr` gives the sequence of rows.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
    group_by(gr = cumsum(Dummy!= dplyr::lag(Dummy, default= Dummy[1L]))) %>% 
    mutate(Dummy_Modified = Dummy *row_number()) %>% 
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-gr)
#         Date Dummy Dummy_Modified
#        (chr) (int)          (int)
#1  2020-01-01     1              1
#2  2020-01-02     0              0
#3  2020-01-03     0              0
#4  2020-01-04     0              0
#5  2020-01-05     1              1
#6  2020-01-06     1              2
#7  2020-01-07     1              3
#8  2020-01-08     0              0
#9  2020-01-09     1              1
#10 2020-01-10     1              2
#11 2020-01-11     0              0
```

Comment: Can this be done using dplyr? I intend to use the group_by feature

Comment: @RajarshiBhadra  The `rleid` is from `data.table`

Comment: If this task is to be done at different item levels ina data set then how should it be modified?

Comment: @RajarshiBhadra  If you meant that there is another grouping column, use that also in the `group_by` or within the `by = .(` in `data.table`

Comment: I don't know who is downvoting a legitimate solution.  Can I know the reason?

Comment: Yep perfect. Your solution worked just the way I wanted. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick

```
df <- data.frame(dummy = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0))
df$dummy_mod <- sequence(rle(df$dummy)$lengths) * df$dummy
df
#    dummy dummy_mod
# 1      1         1
# 2      0         0
# 3      0         0
# 4      0         0
# 5      1         1
# 6      1         2
# 7      1         3
# 8      0         0
# 9      1         1
# 10     1         2
# 11     0         0
```

EDIT: for `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(dummy = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0))
df %>% mutate(dummy_mod = sequence(rle(dummy)[["lengths"]]) * dummy)
```

Comment: Your question didn't mention dplyr. Can you paste a MWE?